# Как реализовать загрузку данных с API в баллун?

Tags: яндекс-карты, yandex-maps-jsapi

Данный код реализует создание баллуна с моим контентом. Можно ли с помощью Vue.js или еще как-то реализовать загрузку данных с API для данных {{магазин}} и {{улица}}.

```
var obj = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: coords.map(function(p){
        return {
            type: 'Feature',
            properties: {
                balloonContent:  '<div class="baloon">' +
                '<img class="img_map" src="https://www.look.com.ua/templates/lookua/images/avatar-user.png" alt="">' +
                '<div class="text">' +
                '<p>'+
                '<p  class="name">{{магазин}}</p>'  +
                '{{улица}}' +
                '<br>' +
                '10:00-22:00' +
                '</p>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="line"></div>' +
                '<p class="proposition">Предложений: 2356/345</p>'
                +'</div>'
            },
            geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [p[0], p[1]]
            }
        }
    })
};


var objects = ymaps.geoQuery(obj);

objects.searchInside(this.myMap).addToMap(this.myMap);

this.myMap.events.add('boundschange', () => {
    var visibleObjects = objects.searchInside(this.myMap).addToMap(this.myMap);
    objects.remove(visibleObjects).removeFromMap(this.myMap);
});
```

Пробовала разобрать в примере https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/om_balloon_ajax, но как-то не пошло((((

Answer (score 2):

Обновить гео-объекты в виде JSON-описания не получится.
Вы можете преобразовать JSON-описание объектов в гео-объекты самостоятельно и затем обновлять свойства уже созданных гео-объектов.

Для шаблонизации `balloonContent` можно использовать встроенный [Template](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Template-docpage/).

```js
var jsonObjectDescriptions = [
  { type: 'Feature', geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [55.75, 37.62] } },
  { type: 'Feature', geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [55.75, 37.52] } },
  { type: 'Feature', geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [55.75, 37.72] } }
];

ymaps.ready(['Map', 'geoQuery', 'Template', 'data.Manager'])
  .then(function() {
    var map = new ymaps.Map('map', { center: [55.75, 37.62], zoom: 10 }, {});

    // Преобразуем JSON-описания в гео-объекты.
    var geoObjects = jsonObjectDescriptions.map(function(json) {
      return new ymaps.GeoObject(json);
    });

    // geoQuery работает с массивом гео-объектов так же
    // как и с JSON-описанием коллекции.
    var objects = ymaps.geoQuery(geoObjects);
    objects.searchInside(map).addToMap(map);
    map.events.add('boundschange', function() { /* ..... */ });

    // Создаем шаблон для balloonContent'а.
    var balloonContentTemplate = new ymaps.Template(
      'магазин: {{магазин}}<br>улица: {{улица}}');

    // Загружаем балуны для всех гео-объекта.
    geoObjects.forEach(function(geoObject) { 
      loadBalloonContent(geoObject, balloonContentTemplate);
    });
  })
  .catch(console.error);

function loadBalloonContent(geoObject, balloonContentTemplate) {
  var coords = geoObject.geometry.getCoordinates();
  
  // Ответ сервера.
  var serverResponse = {
    'магазин': 'колотушкина на ' + coords,
    'улица': 'пушкина'
  };
  
  // Имитируем запрос на сервер через случайный таймаут до 10 секунд.
  ymaps.vow.delay(serverResponse, Math.random() * 10000)
    .then(function(response) {        
      // Строим шаблон.
      var templateData = new ymaps.data.Manager(response);
      var renderedTemplate = balloonContentTemplate.build(templateData);
      
      // Обновляем балун.
      geoObject.properties.set('balloonContent', renderedTemplate.text);
      
      console.log('Загружен балун для гео-объекта на %s', coords)
    })
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

```css
#map {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```